# Cannot boot either Windows 8 or Ubuntu after installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have a HP Envy Desktop that I wanted to dual boot. I used a usb flash drive and installed ubuntu alongside Windows. After restarting my computer, I was unable to load windows, so I used the boot-repair while in legacy mode. I was able to get back into windows, but after restrating my computer I was not able to get into either Windows or Ubuntu and now the machine wont boot to either OS. It only boots from USB. If I have the USB I used to install linux in the port before I start the machine, it goes directly to the GRUB menu where you can choose either to install or try ubuntu. When there is no flash drive in the port, then I get a message about a failed boot disc. I have tried changing the boot order as well as restoring all default settings. Still nothing is working. I am new to the UEFI and Ubuntu and have never dual booted with the UEFI interface.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be best to step back to your original system:

[HP Restore pre-installed windows8 system](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c03489643#N775)

and then install Ubuntu next to your windows by using the guidelines mentioned in this post:

[Installing Ubuntu on a pre-installed windows 8 64 bit uefi system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)